# How to call an external js function from Wasm?

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

I am attempting to call a javascript function from Wasm.

```
package main

import (
    "syscall/js"
)

func main(){
   var args []js.Value
   // set args here...
   js.Global().Get("document").Call("function", "myFunction").Set("args", args)
}
```

Then in HTML I would include my javascript

```
<script src="./js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Where `js/script.js` contains:

```
function myFunction(args){
   console.log(args);
}
```

How do I call myFunction from the Wasm code?

I attempted the suggested solution but it gives me a syntax error.

```
args := js.ValueOf([]interface{"foo", 42})
v := js.Global().Call("myFunction", args)
fmt.Println(v)
```

The terminal looks like

```
$ GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o ./ipickd.wasm ./wasm.go
# command-line-arguments
./wasm.go:44:33: syntax error: unexpected literal "foo", expecting method or interface name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of errors:

- the scope for the function is `Global()`
- `Set` is used to set a property on a `js.Value`, as mentioned in the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value.Set), and is not needed here
- `Call` takes the function name and args as parameters, per the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value.Call)
- `[]js.Value` will probably not do what you want if you want to pass an array

Your go code should be:

```
args := js.ValueOf([]interface{}{"foo", 42})
js.Global().Call("myFunction", args)
```

Or with a one-liner, letting `Call` do the conversion:

```
js.Global().Call("myFunction", []interface{}{"foo", "42"})
```

You can refer to the [js.ValueOf](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#ValueOf) documentation for type compatibility.

Comment: something i dont understand, the doc of `Call` mentions `The arguments get mapped to JavaScript values according to the ValueOf function. ` and it takes `...interface{}`. Is it required to call js.ValueOf in your code ?

Comment: `Call` will indeed convert compatible types to their javascript values. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, seems I mistyped something when I put it in the answer. Fixed now.